# Linq to Entities or SQL Server? Cannot get the results i require. MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am new to MVC / Entity Framework and trying to query the data I require to produce some dashboards.  I am using a Database First model for my MVC project.  Below is the overview of my Table Design.

[image]

Each Member is has a single registered Home Location (Member FK (HomeLocationId) to Location PK (Id), a member can have multiple memberships (Membership FK (MemberId) to Member PK (Id), and finally each Membership has a one to one relationship for its package.

What im trying to do is get a count of the number of members for a specific location based on the package of a users currently active membership.

e.g.  For London (Location) get the count of all Members where their currently active membership (MembershipStateId = 3) and the Package for this active membership as the property PackagePayInFull boolean set to true.

I know in EF and Linq to entities i can get (e.g. db.Locations.Members to get the number of members for a location) but i am unsure how i could extend this query to seemingly do sub queries.  I also am unsure if it would be easier to figure out how to get the data from a single SQL query instead.

I tried creating a method in the member model that would retrieve the activeMembership but then it moans that I am unable to use that query to retrieve the membership object.

```
db.Members.ToList().Where(m => m.HomeLocationId == this.Id && m.getActiveMembership().Package.PackagePayInFull == payinfull).ToList();
```

If someone is able to guide me in the correct direction that would be fantastic.

UPDATE:

I have tried doing a Linq query to create the results but unsure if it is correct. (have i joined correctly based on the relationships)

```
from l in Locations
join m in Members on l.Id equals m.HomeLocationId 
join ms in Memberships on m.Id equals ms.MemberId
where ms.MembershipStateId == 3
join p in Packages on ms.PackageId equals p.Id
where p.PackagePayInFull== true
select new {l, m, ms, p}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The Error message was something like:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method getActiveMembership().  I do realise that I am doing this the wrong way and I am hoping that a more intelligent query would help.

Comment: You can't run code in your linq statement.  i.e. getActiveMembership is not able to be turned into sql syntax which is then ran via the sql engine.  Linq is just essentially turned into a sql statement.  I still get myself into trouble all the time trying to do things kind of like what you are doing there.

Comment: Right..so how would this be done without it?  I'm fairly terrible at SQL statements and unsure how to join on the different tables to get the correct results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you give:

```
var memberCount = context.Members
                         .Where(m => m.Location.Name == "London"
                                  && m.Memberships
                                      .Any(ms => ms.MembershipStateId == 3
                                              && ms.Package.PackagePayInFull))
                         .Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for this..Using Linq pad i have managed to replicate it and get the result that i would have expected so thank you so far for that.. I will need to make some test data to give it a try.